# SSIS "conversion" of decimal fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have a SSIS package that copies data from one database to another.
The datatype of the source column is `decimal(18, 3)` and the datatype of the destination column is `decimal(18, 2)`.

When executing the SSIS package, I get the following error:

> [Address [2]] Error: There was an error with Address.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[KoordinateNorth] on Address.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

- Isn't SSIS rounding / truncating the decimal places?
- How can I import the data without changing the destination data type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It isn't converting - otherwise you wouldn't be getting the error!
2. You need to transform your data. Have a look at either the Data Conversion or Derived column tasks to help you move from one datatype to another.

Comment: Please pay attention that in Derived Column - you need to create a new column in Dataflow. Storing converted data in the same column will not replace its metadata and data length specifically, and will not resolve your error.